# chai mocha TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to add tdd to my website. However, I'm having an issue getting mocha/chai to run.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

//var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../app');

var m_Kbase_data = require('../model/Kbase');
var m_KbaseScript_schema = require('../model/KbaseScript');


var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('KBase', function() {
      beforeEach(function(done){
        //m_Kbase_data.collection.drop();
        //m_Kbase_data.save(function(err) {
          done();
        //});
      });
//    afterEach(function(done){
//        m_Kbase_data.collection.drop();
//      //done();
//    });

      it('does a thing', function () {
          return chai.request('/kbase')
          .then(function () {
            expect(1).to.equal(1);
          });
    });
});
```

I have verified that my database is has the collection and is working.

If I have the server up and running and run the test, I get an extra error "Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE"

All other errors are "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: I haven't gotten it totally, but I have one working now. I had to change this: var expect = chai.expect; However, it still isn't linking to the server it would appear.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently works for the code I have:

```
  it('does a thing', function (done) {
      chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
      .get('/kbase')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        expect(1).to.equal(1);
        done();
      });
});
```

I'm getting a passed now.